# Fixing div to the top and not apply on children

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to fix the parent *div* on top, while the children div do not apply to this styling. When scrolling down, the content in the children *div* should go beneath the parent. For instance, take that I have the following code written:

Here's my code:

```css
.parent {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;

    .children {
        top: 50px;
        // clear: both;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
      Heading Here Fixed Top

      <div class="children">
          <div class="scroll">
          The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori...
          </div>
          <div class="scroll">
          The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori...
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**Please note that the fix is important without the use of extra elements added, including moving elements arounds. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: take the child divs outside of parent.

Comment: @Sfili_81, that is a great solution; except that I will be modifying the architecture. I will edit the question to emphasize not moving elements around.

Comment: without modifying the architecture i think you can't only with css. also your child elements is fixed as it's parent. Try to read something about sticky position

Comment: Is JS/Jquery allowed?

Comment: @GogoDev, yes! You may suggest anything relating to JS/JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use JavaScript as follows:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const child = document.getElementById('child');
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    child.style.top = -window.scrollY + 'px';
  });
};
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 300vh;
}

.parent {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: aqua;
}

.children {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
      Heading Here Fixed Top

      <div id="child" class="children">
          <div class="scroll">
          The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori...
          </div>
          <div class="scroll">
          The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labori...
          </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You add an extra div... OP don't want extra elements... with an extra div you can do this without js

Comment: @Sfili_81, true! With an extra element it becomes easier without JS/jQuery...

Comment: @DESH I edited the answer. check it out. is that ok?